# How to make a where in a documentReference?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I need to search for all persons (persons) with active profiles (personProfiles).

I'm a little confused by documentReference.

```
const personsRef = firebase.firestore().collection('persons');

const personsRef = await personsRef.get();
const result = [];

for (let index = 0; index < personsRef.docs.length; index += 1) {

    const person = personsRef.docs[index].data();

    if (person.personProfile) {

        const personProfileRef = await person.personProfile.get();

        const personProfileData = personProfileRef.data();

        if (personProfileData?.active) {
            result.push({ name: person.name });
        }

    }

}
```

My structure:

**persons**

[image]

**personProfiles**

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't really clear to me.  What are you confused about?  You can't make a filtered query based off a DocumentReference.  All you can do with the document it refers to is `get()` it.

Comment: something like 
persons.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.where('personProfiles.active', '==', true);
    });

Comment: can I make a clause where in documentReference, without having to call get?

Comment: Still not clear what you're trying to do.  A where clause filters documents from a collection.  You start with a collection, the add where clauses to it to narrow down the results using some criteria.

Comment: I need to filter the data in a collection, the attribute for the filter is in the collection reference. sorry for not being so clear

Comment: OK, sounds doable.  What isn't working about the code you're showing?  There are a lot of variables in there that we don't know the value of.

Comment: updated my code snippet

Comment: I didn't like my solution

Comment: So your code is actually working and you want to optimize it, is that the case? Also, why are you keeping `/personProfile/` on the persons document? That is unecessary since the id of the `personProfile` is only what follows that, correct?

Comment: I want to optimize it! @ralemos

Comment: The attributes that are in personProfiles are not part of a "person", so I decided to separate them. makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it could either be a subcollection or a completely separate one that holds a reference by id that is correct, but I want to know why you are keeping `/personProfile/` on the reference to personProfile's id, that seems unecessary and error prone, since ideally you would have to separate that from the original id (which is the remaining text) in order to get the document.

Comment: is "SQL" thinking. Search for a collection by executing the where in other clause

Comment: What do you suggest to do in a scenario: Take all the people who are active, returning the name field and the active field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was already functional as you mentioned on the comments, I made a few changed for removing the async parts of your code and adding them to a `then()` call and simplified a bit of the conditions you had, this is what I come up with:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const personsRef = db.collection('persons');

personsRef.get().then((snapshot){
    snapshot.foreach((document){
        const personProfile = document.data().personProfile;
        if (personProfile) {
            db.collection('personProfile')
              .document(personProfile)
              .get().then((doc){
                const docData = doc.data()
                if (docData.active) {
                    result.push({ name: docData.name });
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

**NOTE**: As I mentioned on the comments, this assumes that the `personProfile` field of the `persons` collection was changed to not contain `/personProfile/` anymore so you can query directly by id in the second `get()`. So as an example, the document that you shared on your screenshot would only have `XktK7SdqinS4uwdXCXD0nQ400kB2` on it;s `personProfile`. If this is not possible to be changed for some reason, you will have to do something like this:

```
const personProfile = document.data().personProfile.subStr(
     15, document.data().personProfile.length
);
```